# Headless Installation of OpenBSD?

Tags: headless, freebsd

My Raspberry Pi 3 USB ports are not working, they suddenly stopped functioning and I don't know why.

Now I want to install OpenBSD/FreeBSD but, as my USB ports are damaged or not working, I want to install them by Headless installation (without attaching a keyboard or HDMI display).

Is there any way to do a headless installation of OpenBSD/FreeBSD via ssh server? Is it enabled by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RPi3 support for OpenBSD is incomplete. Not even old Beagle has USB code, after 5 years. Expect the same with PI3.

Use FreeBSD flashed images you can find [here](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi). Many things work for RPi3. NetBSD works 99% IIRC. See [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=86).

Unless you need something specifically *BSD, Raspbian is better.

On the FreeBSD images, SSHD is enabled on first boot, so you can immediately login and resize fs, add packages etc. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks, I already used **Raspbian**  a lot.But, wanted to try  **OpenBSD**  on raspberry or at least **FreeBSD**  just to learn **PF** .

Now, successfully completed the headless installation of  **FreeBSD** on Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: @NeerajPal Yeah, pf is just so much sleeker than iptables. Enjoy.

Comment: @user2497 Can you please provide link of NetBSD that is working  for RPi 3 ?

Comment: @fugitive Use bleeding edge NetBSD-CURRENT

Answer (score 0):

For FreeBSD it is very straight forward. sshd is enabled by default, so the hardest part of the whole process will be finding the IP address of the Pi. Pinging the broadcast address and then running `arp -a` was how I did it.

After that do:

`ssh freebsd@<the IP address you found>`

then login with the password of `freebsd.`

I would imagine that it would be pretty much the same for OpenBSD.

Comment: No, it's simple, it depends on what are you doing to make it simple and easy. Like, what I do is  configure LAN port to give output (packet flow from LAN port  to external connected device, kind of reverse of general use of LAN port) then I connect Raspberry Pi via LAN port and then my main os like laptop allocates new private IP to raspberry pi then you can do arp-scan or whatever you want to do.